# How can I keep only 5 features on display with a WMS layer requested from GeoServer via a SQL view?

Tags: sql, postgis, geoserver, bounding-box, wms

I set up a PostGIS database that I added in GeoServer via a parameterized SQL view. I use Leaflet to display this layer via WMS.

I would like to limit the number of features I see in the bounding box (5 maximum in my case). I tried to add a LIMIT 5 at the end of my SQL view but it affects the number of features on the whole map not in the bouding box.

Here is a simplified example to illustrate the issue. The aim is to get the 5 most populated cities located in the bounding box. It would work if Geoserver made this query :

```
SELECT geometry FROM table_cities 
WHERE geometry && ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON ((-5.185 41.954, -5.185 51.374, 23.378 51.374, 23.378 41.954, -5.185 41.954))',
4326) 
ORDER BY population LIMIT 5
```

But instead it wraps the SQL view inside a new SELECT dedicated to keep only the features located in the bounding box:

```
SELECT geometry FROM 
(SELECT geometry FROM table_cities ORDER BY population LIMIT 5) 
WHERE geometry && ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON ((-5.185 41.954, -5.185 51.374, 23.378 51.374, 23.378 41.954, -5.185 41.954))',
4326)
```

Is there a way to force Geoserver to put the bouding box verification before the LIMIT 5 selection?

Or maybe there is a different method to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the [Geoserver Where Clause placeholder](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html#place-holder-for-the-sql-where-clause) `:where_clause:`

Because an `and` is automatically/systematically added, you must already have a `where clause`, even if it is a dummy `1=1` clause that always evaluate to true.

```sql
SELECT geometry 
FROM table_cities 
WHERE 1 = 1 :where_clause:
ORDER BY population 
LIMIT 5
```

Note the absence of `and` between the `1=1` and `:where_clause:`

Comment: This :where_clause: feature is great. It's exactly what I needed thanks!